# Paypal direct debit

Tags: paypal

I am developing an application, where consumer pays 10GBP for each service. My client wants functionality that allows them to link an application account with a Paypal account. This way the customer won't have to log into Paypal each payment request, but just make allow Paypal to fetch money from account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can consider Reference Transaction with Billing agreement?

See here : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

Comment: I have made some deeper research, and that's what i'm looking for. Regret it's available only in NVP/SOAP not in REST api.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking looking for a subscription button, where the customer signs up to your 10GBP monthly service and then it automatically rebills them every month.

Follow these instructions to create the button.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_step_1/

Comment: It's not like a subscription. Customer chooses a service from dynamically changing set, and after that he have to pay 10 GBP. To payments are not scheduled- it's totally random.